# Rounding corners on UICollectionview and not individual cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uibezierpath, rounded-corners

I'm trying to have 2 rounded top corners on my `UICollectionView`

I have a `UIView` **contentView** that contains my `UICollectionView`. If I set the cornerRadius of my `UICollectionView` and set clipsToBound to true, this works except that it rounds **all 4 corners**.

So it would seem I need to apply a `UIBezierPath` but once I do that I hit the problems:

1. If I apply the `UIBezierPath` to the `UICollectionView` itself, I can only see my first cell and when I scroll to the second cell, I can't see anything.

[

```
[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.collectionView.bounds
 byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(9.0,
 9.0)];     
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = self.collectionView.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
self.collectionView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

2. If I try to apply the `UIBezierPath` to the **contentView** instead, same as above but I replace **self.collectionView** with **self.contentView**, the corners are not rounded at all.

Comment: Have you tried adding a corner radius to the whole collectionView and setting clipsToBounds to YES?

Comment: @Rikh please see my edited question

Comment: Are you over riding the drawRect for the collectionViewCell or collectionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `UIBezierPath` on the `UICollectionView` parent container worked as long as the parent view **wasn't my first/top view**. I had to add another `UIView` **roundContainerView** to my top `UIView`.

```
UIView ( Top view. contentView )

  |- UIView ( roundContainerView ) apply UIBezierPath here

       |- UICollectionView ( collectionView )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about rounded the view which your collectionView locates?

Something like this:

```
let viewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
let corners: UIRectCorner = .topLeft
let path = UIBezierPath(
    roundedRect: viewFrame,
    byRoundingCorners: corners,
    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = viewFrame
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
view.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Comment: The corners are not rounded at all if I apply the UIBezierPath to the contentView that contains my UICollectionView. See my edited question.